# NSIS Invalid command: ShellExecAsUser::ShellExecAsUser

Tags: plugins, dll, nsis

When I try to use the ShellExecAsUser plugin for NSIS, I get the following error.

```
Invalid command: ShellExecAsUser::ShellExecAsUser
```

This only started to happen after I upgraded the NSIS script compiler, so I guess they helpfully changed how `makensis` searches for plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [!addplugindir](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#5.1.3) compiler utility command, which tells NSIS where to look for the plugin.

Comment: ...or you can put the `ShellExecAsUser.dll` plugin into the `Plugins` subdirectory of the NSIS application directory.

Comment: @Seki That would work, but asking devs to do this is not always practical.